# Why is Beautifulsoup Displaying Scrape URLs with Unnecessary Characters

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5, google-search

I tried other types of css selectors and xpaths, so I am assuming I may be using the library incorrectly but there is no documentations that is not telling me otherwise. I also tried other bs4 functions such as find_all, but many do not return any other results. Any type of help would be appreciated, Cheers!

Code:

```
    import bs4 as bs
    from requests import get

    query = input('Please Enter Your Topic of intrest: ')

    first_part = query.replace(" ", "%20")
    second_part = query.replace(" ", "+")
    results= "0"

    num_of_pages = int(input('How many pages do you want scraped? '))

    for i in range(num_of_pages):
    results= int(results)
    results += 10

    gsearch_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}#q={}%3F&start={}&*".format(first_part, second_part, results)

    sauce = get(gsearch_url)

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'lxml')

    for url in soup.select('.r a'):
        print(url.get('href'))
```

Return:

```
    /url?q=http://www.codingdojo.com/blog/9-most-in-demand-programming-languages-of-2016/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwja3a21w7fSAhWSZiYKHdLGA9gQFggdMAI&usg=AFQjCNFmDl_1epVQRmDfc4y5MWFeNvrPQg
    /url?q=https://fossbytes.com/best-popular-programming-languages-2017/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwja3a21w7fSAhWSZiYKHdLGA9gQFgghMAM&usg=AFQjCNEKhYqx1FbKl_Wu-9EoMYd3e9i_Dw
    /url?q=http://www.bestprogramminglanguagefor.me/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwja3a21w7fSAhWSZiYKHdLGA9gQFggnMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHmbzuLwFo_egaWnbXSOW4p-Fva3g
    /url?q=http://www.codingdojo.com/blog/9-most-in-demand-programming-languages-of-2016/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwja3a21w7fSAhWSZiYKHdLGA9gQFggyMAU&usg=AFQjCNFmDl_1epVQRmDfc4y5MWFeNvrPQg
   etc....
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, please state your desired return(result) and render your code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

First off, scraping Google's search results breaks their terms of service. So, somewhere on the internets the great Alphabet is wagging a finger and furrowing its brow. Oh yeah, you'll probably get slapped with a captcha at some point too.

Second, and *ahem* purely to resolve any remaining academic curiosity, the results you're getting are not caused by BeautifulSoup. It's actually what Google is returning. You can check it by doing a `print(soup)` and perusing the html. You'll notice all your `href`'s match exactly to what you're printing out.

Why does this look different than what you see in your browser? The magic of `javascript`! Which the `requests` library does not handle, so you're seeing the results without all the client-side processing.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
# calls for ".yuRUbf a" css selector and grabs "href" attribute (link)
soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",     # query
  "gl": "us",                                   # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                                    # language    
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(title, link, sep='\n')
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to extract the data from the structured JSON rather than figuring out why things don't work and then maintain it over time if some selectors will change.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.